# Sql select query help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following table structure inside my aanmeldingen table:

```
username      varchar(16) NOT NULL
introduce_van varchar(16) NULL
```

I have the follow 3 rows of data:

```
Username Introduce_van   
Test1    NULL
Test2    Test1
Test3    NULL
```

Now I want to select all username are not in Introduce_van and Introduce_van's value is NULL.

I tried it with this sql:

```
SELECT username 
FROM aanmeldingen 
WHERE username NOT IN
      (SELECT introduce_van  
       FROM aanmeldingen 
       WHERE introduce_van != 'NULL')
```

This query returns:

```
Test2, Test3
```

So I thought If I would add:

```
AND introduce_van = 'NULL'
```

It would return just Test3.

But it returns 0 rows.

I just can't figure out how to fix my select query to make sure it only return Test3(Not in Introduce_van and having Introduce_van NULL.

Can someone help me out with this query?

Answer (score 0):

When checking for null values, it's either

```
is null
```

or

```
is not null
```

The rest of your logic was almost ok.  You have to move the check for null values outside your subquery,

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is to use `LEFT JOIN` and filter *NULL* values using `IS NULL` and not `=! NULL`.

```
SELECT  a.UserName
FROM   tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON a.username = b.Introduce_van
WHERE   b.Introduce_van IS NULL AND   
        a.Introduce_van IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e6a3/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╗
║ USERNAME ║
╠══════════╣
║ Test3    ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: This will select the rows where Introduce_van is null not where introduce van is some value other than the userName

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked for me. Also thanks to all the others that tried to help me.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as `accepted` by clicking the white check mark (*around 15 mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "Now I want to select all username are not in Introduce_van ***OR*** Introduce_van's value is NULL." ???

If so, use this:

```
 SELECT Distinct username 
 FROM aanmeldingen a 
 WHERE introduce_van Is Null  
     Or Not exists 
      (SELECT * FROM aanmeldingen 
       WHERE introduce_van = a.userName)
```